# Property 'pseudoStyle' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3, pseudo-element

I'm trying to modify the pseudo element's height using Typescript.

I'm getting the following error in my IDE (vscode)

This is my code.

```
// select element
let el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('filter-container');
//  style the height of psydo element
el.pseudoStyle("before", "height", newHeight);
...
```

Comment: `HTMLElement` interface doesn't have `pseudoStyle` property in it. That's why it throws error in IDE.
You can do something like this `let el: any = document.getElementById('filter-container');`

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani I tried with any, it gives the error 
el.pseudoStyle is not a function

Comment: Do you get that error in VS code IDE or during run time?

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani at run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't style a pseudo-class on a particular element alone, you can do it by altering the stylesheet:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('#id:hover { background-color: blue; }', 0);
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor= 'blue';
```

Answer (score 1):

try `el.prototype.pseudoStyle("before", "height", newHeight);`

Answer (score 1):

As I know in JavaScript we can't change pseudo elements and I guess same in TS because of it is a JS superset. 
With best regards.